# Element fade in on scroll PURE vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, typescript

I am looking to have elements fade in as you scroll to them. The catch is I need it in pure vanilla javascript...absolutely no jquery. Everything I am finding online is in jquery which is a struggle. I am using tweenMax for my animation.Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    if(window.scrollY > 550){
    TweenMax.staggerFromTo(newProduct, 1, {opacity:0}, {opacity:1}, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Is this in a `window.scroll` event? If so, you'd be triggering your animation over and over, meaning it might never be given the time to complete.

Comment: If you want the opacity to relate to the scroll position, you may end up going *really* vanilla and animating without any library like Tweenmax, which focuses on time-based animation (not scroll position based).

Answer (score 4):

Here I've used CSS to fade in / out.

On scroll I check to see if element is viewport, if so I add the class inview, else I remove it.  If you want to make it so that it only fades in you can alter the selector to exclude the inview class.

```js
let section = document.createElement('section');
document.body.appendChild(section);
for (let x = 1; x <= 100; x ++) {
  let d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerText = `Hello there div line ${x} of 100`;
  section.appendChild(d);
}
  
function inView (el) {
  var sb = section.getBoundingClientRect();
  var eb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return !((eb.top + eb.height < 0) || (eb.top > sb.height));
}

function updateInView() {
  for (x of document.querySelectorAll('div')) {
    if (inView(x)) x.classList.add('inview')
    else x.classList.remove('inview');
  }
}

section.onscroll = updateInView;

updateInView();
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

div.inview {
  opacity: 1;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let section = document.createElement('section');
document.body.appendChild(section);
for (let x = 1; x <= 100; x ++) {
  let d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerText = `Hello there div line ${x} of 100`;
  section.appendChild(d);
}
  
function inView (el) {
  var sb = section.getBoundingClientRect();
  var eb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return !((eb.top + eb.height < 0) || (eb.top > sb.height));
}

function updateInView() {
  for (x of document.querySelectorAll('div')) {
    if (inView(x)) x.classList.add('inview')
    else x.classList.remove('inview');
  }
}

section.onscroll = updateInView;

updateInView();
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20vh);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out, transform 1.2s ease-out;
  will-change: opacity, visibility;
}

div.inview {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
  visibility: visible;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This looks much nicer

## References

> [How to fade content as it scrolls into view | selbekk.io](https://www.selbekk.io/blog/2019/08/how-to-fade-in-content-as-it-scrolls-into-view/)